# Using past tense with progressive form when talking about tasks that wil be completed in the future

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-continuous

Can I use the following form:

> Please tell me when you finished filling in this form.

Or does it have to be something along the lines of:

> Please tell me when you have finished filling in this form.

Comment: @Cardinal So how would I request someone to report back upon completion of given task ?

Comment: The first is talking about the past, asking for information about when the task was completed. The second is talking about the future asking for notification of the task completion. Using "notify" rather than "tell" might be easier to understand.

Comment: @Cardinal my interpretation of the intent is not to ask for a prediction of when but rather to contacted at that time. Your formulations are good if indeed a prediction is being asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence

> Please tell me when you finished filling in this form.

is not correct, you could use either present or present perfect

> Please tell me when you *are finished* filling in this form.
>   Please tell me when you *have finished* filling in this form.

alternatively you could use

> Please tell me when you *finish* filling in this form.

All three mean "upon completion, please let me know".

Comment: Doesn't the first one refer to *a past completion*? 'Please tell me when you finished filling in this form; I think you were the first one to finish it.' Compare 'Please tell me when you washed your car; Sara says you did it between 3 and 4pm, but I thought I saw you downtown at 3:30'

Comment: @AlanCarmack You are correct that it can be understood that way, but the OP was asking in the question title "about tasks that will be completed in the future".